# Metadata image from audio file?

Tags: javascript, image, audio, metadata

I want to retrieve the metadata of an audio file with javascript/php.

I have the information like artist,album etc. i use a library

http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/08/reading-id3-tags-with-javascript.html

Now i also want to retrieve the picture associated with the files. Mostly songs come with a cover picture or similar kind of picture. I wantt to extract the picture. Any libraries or code that can be used for the purpose??

Thanx.